# How to store more than 2 variables in an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

How can I store more than 2 variables in an `std::unordered_map`?

I want something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<string, int, int, int> mapss = {{"a",1,1,1},{"b",1,2,3}};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `string` is the key, and the rest are values, then you could have the value be a `tuple`.

```
unordered_map<string, tuple<int, int, int>> mapss
```

Of if you don't know how many values will be there, you can use a `vector`

```
unordered_map<string, vector<int>> mapss
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use an `std::tuple`, as Cyber mentioned, but I suggest creating a simple `struct` if you know what the values represent.

It expresses your intent clearly.

Example:

```
struct Color
{
    int r, g, b;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Color> colors = 
{
    {"red",  {255, 0, 0}},
    {"blue", {0, 0, 255}}
};
```