# unordered_multimap: values as tuples or vectors

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I want to build an `std::unordered_map` in which values are not single strings, ints or floats but tuples, vectors or structures. I know this can be done as @Vittorio_Romeo and @CoryKramer explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796290/how-to-store-more-than-2-variables-in-an-unordered-map). However, I'm finding some problems to add new elements to it.

Let me illustrate this with the example provided by @Vittorio_Romeo. Suppose I have the following unordered_map:

```
struct Color
{
    int r, g, b;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Color> colors = 
{
    {"red",  {255, 0, 0}},
    {"blue", {0, 0, 255}}
};
```

Now I want to add another element to this map. I try to do the following:

```
colors.emplace("black",(1,1,1) );
```

Somehow, this doesn't work and I get some errors and notes (which I don't quite understand) in this line:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Color>::pair(const char [6], int)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could it be a problem of my compiler (gcc version 5.4.1)?. I'd appreciate any help with this. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no tuple or vector in your code.

Comment: About _"Could it be a problem of my compiler?"_: there is basicly three steps in a developer life. 1/ "My problem is due to a compiler bug/a cpu bug/...". 2/ "I know it comes from ma code, the compiler/cpu is always right". 3/"Ho shit! this time it _really_ was a compiler/cpu bug! Brilliant!".

Comment: @manni66 you're right, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @YSC Thanks for your remark. I guess I'm somewhere between 1/ and 2/ and not reaching 3/ anytime soon =) I'll try my best though!

Comment: Note: there is an hidden fourth step "Oops, compiler bug, I'll fix it quickly and hope nobody sees it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(1, 1, 1)` is the expression `1,1,1` inside parentheses, nothing more. And `1,1,1` is equal to `(1,1),1` using the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) twice, and the result is the single `int` value `1`.

You need to explicitly specify a `Color` object, using e.g. `Color{1,1,1}` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't just replacing the braces with curly braces work too?

Comment: @SeanBurton Unfortunately not in that context.